# Facing error with "Get Started With Oracle Database 11g Express Edition' short cut on desktop

Tags: oracle

I have installed Oracle XE 11.2 on my system. My system is running on Window7. When I try to open Oracle console from Desktop short cut, it gives me following error.

[image]

But it works fine with internet URL : "http//127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950:1:3802479032384355".

Can anyone suggest me what is the problem with the short cut?

Comment: Looks like the %HTTPPORT% environment variable hasn't been set?

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp : You were correct. After setting HTTPPORT as 8080 in Environment Variable, its working. Thanks for Quick Suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It is working  fine After setting "HTTPPORT" AS 8080 in Environment Variables. Environment Variable entry was missing.